# Angular - Render components inside custom component

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
<app-device [device]="device">
        <app-custom-slide-toggle></app-custom-slide-toggle>
        <app-custom-checkbox-list></app-custom-checkbox-list>
      </app-device>
```

How I can show my `app-custom-slide-toggle`,`app-custom-checkbox-list` components in a specific location inside my `app-device` component?

I was reading about loading dynamic components, but couldn't figure how how to make it work in compuond components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's content projection.

```
<app-device [device]="device">
  <app-custom-slide-toggle slot-one></app-custom-slide-toggle>
  <app-custom-checkbox-list slot-two></app-custom-checkbox-list>
</app-device>
```

And now in `AppDeviceComponent` we should make slots for content:

```
<!-- device.component.html -->
<div>
    <div class="slot-1">
        <ng-content select="[slot-one]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="slot-2">
        <ng-content select="[slot-two]"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another cases with detailed description are [here](https://dev.to/imm9o/angular-content-projection-the-complete-guide--3dcb).